# Swift popup view not displaying from another popup view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, popup

I am new on swift and I would like to show myFirst popup view, then when I clicked a button inside myFirst popup view, I would like to dismiss myFirst popup view and open mySecond popup view. But after myFirst popup view dissmissed, mySecond popup view not presenting..

Here is what I tried so far;

To open myFirst popup:

```
presentPopupView(myFirst!)
```

it is working fine, then when I clicked button in this popup view, I am doing this:

```
        self.dismissPopupView()

        self.presentPopupView(mySecond!)
```

In here, myFirst popup dissmiss correctly. But there is no mySecond popup view displaying..

Any advise? Thanks

Update: I am using STZPopupView [library](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/STZPopupView)

Here is presentPopupView method:

```
public func presentPopupView(_ popupView: UIView, config: STZPopupViewConfig = STZPopupViewConfig()) {

    if self.containerView != nil {
        return
    }

    let containerView = UIView(frame: targetView.bounds)
    containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    let overlayView = UIView(frame: targetView.bounds)
    overlayView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    overlayView.backgroundColor = config.overlayColor
    containerView.addSubview(overlayView)

    // blur effect
    if let blurStyle = config.blurEffectStyle {
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: blurStyle))
        blurEffectView.frame = containerView.frame;
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        containerView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }

    let dismissButton = UIButton(frame: targetView.bounds)
    dismissButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    containerView.addSubview(dismissButton)
    if config.dismissTouchBackground {
        dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissPopupView), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }

    popupView.center = CGPoint(x: targetView.bounds.midX, y: targetView.bounds.midY)
    popupView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin,
                                  .flexibleTopMargin,
                                  .flexibleRightMargin,
                                  .flexibleBottomMargin]
    popupView.layer.cornerRadius = config.cornerRadius
    containerView.addSubview(popupView)

    targetView.addSubview(containerView)

    self.containerView = containerView
    self.popupView = popupView
    self.config = config

    showAnimation()
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the presentPopupView(..) method and as well exactly where you do dismissPopupView()? Just put a bit more code in your question so we can orientate you for a better answer within your context

Comment: @denis_lor updated

Comment: Alright, sounds like few things going on there. Also we need to know what the dismiss is doing, but eventually you could have played a bit outside those two methods with the container or target view, so better to debug in another way. Lets put some `print("DEBUG_KEY", "...")` within `func presentPopupView(_ popupView: UIView, config: STZPopupViewConfig = STZPopupViewConfig())`. Before the if self... something like `print("DEBUG_KEY", "before container view check for nil")` and after the check something like `print("DEBUG_KEY", "target bounds: \(targetView.bounds)")`

Comment: let us know what happens when you show the first popup and when you dismiss the first and try to show the second, what are the outputs for the printing tag `DEBUG_KEY`?